# How to use thread by using c++ in my case?

Tags: c++, thread-safety

I have a function to calculate the value in real time

```
void task() {
   while(true) {
   ...//calculate value(value will change every loop)
   }
}
```

In the main thread, my code is as follow, i want to use the real time value which i got from task thread,

```
int main() {
   ...
   while(true) {
       int v = value;//value is calculated from task thread in real time
       ....

   }

}
```

The main Thread will cost about 0.5s one loop, so i want to get the lastest value to update the v in next loop,How can i do this?

It's my first time to use Thread in c++,i don't know how to write the code.Can someone help me.Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Use `std::atomic<int>` if you can.

Comment: Google for the producer-consumer problem. You will find some hints how to implement this.

Comment: In my answer I note an argument in calling creating the thread. You would only need to call `std::thread first (task);` for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [`std::thread`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread) for basic threading in general. In case of an int depending on the platform, it might simply work. If you want to be sure, use an `std::atomic<int>`

```
std::atomic<int> global_value;

void task() {
   while(true) {
   ...//calculate value(value will change every loop)
      global_value.store(value);
   }
}

int main() {
   ...
   while(true) {
       int v = global_value.load();
       ....
   }
}
```

`std::atomic<int>` will make sure, that all read and write accesses are atomic.

Comment: _In case of an int on most platforms, you can simply use it_ - That is pretty much not true anywhere, except maybe x86 if you get lucky and your optimizer doesn't screw it up before it even reaches the CPU.

Comment: Wherever I have used ints in a lockfree environment, they behaved atomic, before `std::atomic` was introduced. I don't know all platforms, but this assumption does often hold. Since there obviously are platforms where that assumptions does not hold, the standards committee has introduced `std::atomic` and therefore I have proposed that here as well. Whenever the platform has atomic `int`s, the compiler will not generate any overhead, so using `std::atomic` is surely the most safe bet here.

Comment: But if the type is not int,a new datatype how can i do that?

Comment: That is why I wrote: "in case of an int [...]". To be more clear, what I tried to say: sometimes things just work with `int`. If you want to be sure, use `std::atomic`.

Comment: I have edited my answer, to improve clarity on what I meant there.

Comment: @ComicSansMS according to http://de.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic `std::atomic_int` is a typedef of `std::atomic<int>`. `std::atomic<int>` has been introduced with C++11 as well, so there is no good reason for your edit.

Comment: @cdonat True, as long as you have the `std::` in front it would still work. I'd still prefer the template version to avoid confusion with the [C version](http://de.cppreference.com/w/c/atomic) from the global namespace.

Answer (score -7):

Make the variable outside main, and above functions.

One thing you could additionally do, is make your function recursive. Then set it up in a `<thread>`, which if you haven't already included, then you're not close to done. A thread is a separate routine running the whole time your other tasks are running. A recursive function is one that calls itself unless one base case is reached. Then it returns. So we need to change your thread's variable, which you can do easily just by following what I said above. Thread instructions at [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/thread/thread/?kw=thread) will help you more. So do try and research it. It's out there. And if you want top level help, there's books as well. You need to have the reading skills to look at code the right way. And the only way you'll learn independence is to stalk the information down and learn it. It's old school, but it'll always work.

```
std::thread first (task,arg);
```

That instances your thread, and you've called it first. So all methods are going to be referenced through `first.` like `first.join()` which will meet you back up with the thread, after you've `first.detach()` from it. In the case you do, you *have to `.join()` again* to destroy it. Much like a pointer. It has become independent of the program at that point, and is running in the background.

If you want to destroy it

```
first.~thread();
```

Comment: 1. It does not address the question at all. Op was asking how to transfer data between a worker thread and main. 2. It is in places factually wrong. Eg. there is no `terminate` member function in `std::thread`; You cannot join a detached thread... 3. It encourages bad practices. Detaching a thread is a dangerous thing to do and should only be attempted after careful consideration. For this particular problem, it is almost certainly the wrong thing to do.

Comment: If i retype it, i can make all those things right. And terminate? That's called by ~thread(). I thought that was implying on cplusplus.com that one could use it.

Comment: `std::terminate` is a stand-alone function that will terminate _the whole program_. It is called to indicate that something is seriously wrong beyond the point of possible recovery. You are welcome to adjust your answer by editing and I will happily remove my downvote if you can significantly improve it. But as it stands currently, I'm afraid the downvotes are well-deserved.